# CodeIgniter/PyroCMS data reference within jQuery function (getJSON) to emulate Medium.com

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a PyroCMS installation I'm working with (powered by CodeIgniter) and I've run into a snag. The desired functionality for the blog is to mimic the transitions used in Medium, following this tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MediumStylePageTransition/#1

I've added the relevant .js and .css files to the install, and reference them properly on the front end, but how do I direct the .getJSON call within the function to pull its data from CodeIgniter? Do I use the PyroCMS {{ blog }} loop functionality, and if so, how? Or do I need to take a more direct approach in getting my data?

The relevant JS call:

```
ArticleAnimator.getPost = function(index, callback){
  callback = callback || $.noop;

  if ( this.postCache[index] ){
    callback( this.postCache[index] );
    return;
  }

  var self = this;
  $.getJSON('/data/post_'+ index +'.json', function(d){
    self.postCache[index] = d;
    callback(d)
  });
}
```

My current set-up for view.php with PyroCMS calls:

```
<article class="single_post page hidden">   
{{ post }}
    <div class="big-image"></div>
    <div class="content post-capsule">
        <h5>{{ theme:image file="link.png" }} {{ title }}<small><a href="{{ base:url }}blog" title="Back to the blog">&larr; Back</a></small></h5>

        <div class="post_date">
            <span class="date">
                {{ theme:image file="date.png" }}
                About {{ helper:timespan timestamp=created_on }} ago.
            </span>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="post_body">
            {{ body }}
        </div>

        <div class="post_meta">
            {{ if keywords }}
                {{ theme:image file="tags.png" }}
                <span class="tags">
                    {{ keywords }}
                </span>
            {{ endif }}
        </div>

    </div>
{{ /post }} 
</article>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!